# Apache DrillBit service on all datanodes of hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I am using a 10 node hadoop cluster as below:

- 1 - NameNode
- 1 - ResourceManager
- 8 - Data Nodes

My replication factor is set to 3.

I am planning to use Apache Drill for querying the hadoop data.

Is it required to install drillbit on all the nodes or can I install it only on 3 nodes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**You can install it on as many nodes as you want.**

While running Drill in Distributed mode, make sure -

- Zookeeper is running on cluster
- Edit `drill-override.conf`:

  ```
    drill.exec:{
      cluster-id: "<mydrillcluster>",
      zk.connect: "<zkhostname1>:<port>,<zkhostname2>:<port>, <zkhostname3>:<port>"
     }
  ```

  All the nodes (*on which drill is running*) must have same **cluster-id**.
- You first need to start a Drill daemon (Drillbit) on each node in the cluster.

Reference:

- [installing drill on cluster](https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-the-cluster/)
- [starting drill in distributed mode](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-in-distributed-mode/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need a few more clarification. Lets say that my datanodes were named as DN1 , DN2 , DN3 , DN4 , DN5 , DN6 and DN7. As my replication factor is 3 and block size of 64 MB, assuming a file xyz.csv of 40 MB will be written to DN1 and replicated to DN2 , DN3 and DN4. If I run by drill bit service only on DN5 , DN6 and DN7 , will it be able to get the xyz.csv file data?

Comment: yes, you will be able to query `xyz.csv` (_that's the benefit of distributed system_). If  node on which drillbit is running & node having `xyz.csv` are same then query will be faster due to **data locality**.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that in my case the nodes where drillbit is running and the nodes on which xyz.csv is present are different , still it will be able to query the file xyz.csv but may be with a higher latency.